# How to insert values into database if user selects multiple checkboxes PHP

Tags: php

I have to insert roles for user by using check box but for inserting that  i written a code like but it is inserting  value '1' 3 times (if selected 3 check boxes).

my HTML:

```
<tr>
<td align="right" width="47%" valign="top"><img
        src="images/required_field.gif" /> User Role:</td>
<td width="40%" id="anstr"><input type="checkbox" id="roles_1"
        value="1" name="roles[]" /> <label for="roles_1">X</label><span
        id="levelRole"></span><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="roles_2" value="2" name="roles[]" /> <label
        for="roles_2">Y</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="roles_3" value="3" name="roles[]" /> <label
        for="roles_3">Z</label>
</td>
</tr>
```

my qry:

```
$roles = $_POST['roles'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($roles); $i++) {
    $check_roles = implode(',', $_POST['roles']);
     $sql1 = $db ->query ( "INSERT INTO user_role_xref( user_id, user_role_id, created_on)
    VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_user_role_id, :p_created_on)", 
    array (
        'p_user_id' => 81,
         'p_user_role_id' => $check_roles,
         'p_created_on' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
         )
    );

}
```

Please help me how to do it.

Comment: could you elaborate/rephrase properly. Also i suggest to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function before inserting for `$check_roles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't really understand the `implode(',', $_POST['roles'])`. Should the roles be saved comma separated into one column? As the sql column says `user_role_id`, not `ids` (plural) i would think there is a record for each separate role.

First of all, try `foreach`, much easier to read and write than a for loop, and it does the trick brilliantly. Try something like this;

```
foreach ($roles as $role_id) {
    $sql1 = $db ->query ( "INSERT INTO user_role_xref( user_id, user_role_id, created_on)
        VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_user_role_id, :p_created_on)", 
        array (
            'p_user_id' => 81,
            'p_user_role_id' => $role_id,
            'p_created_on' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: oh and btw, if you want to start numbers with three, then why do you have number 1 and 2 set in your html form...? and if role ids 1 and 2 should not be set, test, in your php scrtip, for those values...

Comment: Also i suggest to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function before inserting for `$role_id` as said before.

Comment: well it seems some kind of value sanitizer is already used in his $sql object (why would he insert some array and have value names prefixed with :p_?). So in this case it would not be necessary. But to poster; please check if this is correct, otherwise it IS a serious security risk...

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_3" value="3" name="roles[]" />
...
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_4" value="4" name="roles[]" />
...
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_5" value="5" name="roles[]" />
```

on the HTML side would help for the value range

```
$roles = $_POST['roles'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($roles); $i++) {
     $sql1 = $db ->query ( "INSERT INTO user_role_xref( user_id, user_role_id, created_on)
    VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_user_role_id, now())", 
    array (
        'p_user_id' => 81,
         'p_user_role_id' => $roles[$i]
         )
    );

}
```

should fix the PHP